# #Define Macro error

Tags: c

I have this define set up on top and im getting an error when calling it

```
/*-------------------__RETURN DEFINE-----------------*/
    #define __return(x) \
    pool_err= POOL_PUTSPACE_(i_exit_cb->Pool_addr,&l);\
    if ( pool_err != 0 )  \
     { exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } \
    return(x);
   /*---END OF __RETURN DEFINE-----*/
```

i get an error like below (g is a struct and csr_val is value inside assigned as a short)

```
 __return(g->csr_val);
     Warning 86: argument 2 conflicts with formal definition
```

Comment: Note that symbol names starting with underscores are reserved for the compiler.

Comment: Is g a struct or a _pointer_ to a struct? If the former, it'd be g.csr_val.

Comment: The only thing with 2 arguments in that code snippet is `POOL_PUTSPACE_`.  So what is that?  And what is `l`?  (Again, `l` is not a great choice of name!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error mention the second (2) parameter and the only function call with 2 parameters is to `POOL_PUTSPACE_`. I would guess that the `&l` might need a cast.

Answer (score 1):

Identifiers beginning with `__` are reserved for compiler use. Perhaps `__return` is conflicting with an internally defined macro or function?